# How to get converted currency amount in Braintree?

Tags: currency, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I have multiple merchant accounts in Braintree and my settlement currency is USD. Let's say I charge a credit card 10 CAD then according to Braintree documentation the converted USD amount (lets say 7 USD) will be deposited into my account.

I want to know is there any API I can use to get the converted USD amount (i.e. 7) by passing the transaction id or something?
I don't want to go to the control panel and download the transaction-level fee report for every transaction. I need to automate the process for our internal invoicing purposes.